# TCL multi level dictionary - how to update same key by appending to it

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I have a dict called test, I wish to iteratively update the same key by appending new items to it. So eventually it would look like this

**AIM**

```
test {
1 {flps {o1 o2 o3 ...}}
}
```

**What is the standard way to do this** ? I have the below code right now:

```
set test [dict create] ;
dict set test 1 "flps" "o1"   ;  #### first value o1 added
set new "[dict get $test 1 regs] o2" ; ##temp variable that append the old + new value
dict set test 1 regs $new         ; ### does dict set overwrite ?
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the standard way to do this ?

There is no built-in command for this purpose, one approach is to use `dict update`:

```
% set test [dict create]
% dict update test 1 1 { dict lappend 1 flps "o1" }
flps o1
% set test
1 {flps o1}
% dict update test 1 1 { dict lappend 1 flps "o2" }
flps {o1 o2}
% set test
1 {flps {o1 o2}}
```

However, this easily becomes unhandy when there are more levels of nesting or even an unknown nesting depth.

Comment: Look for some [custom commands](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/dict+lappend) at the Tclers' wiki.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
dict update test 1 1 {dict lappend 1 flps "o1" } ; ## here why do we have 1 1 after dict update test  ?

Comment: Did you check the [`dict update`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M25) manual entry? `dict update` maps each entry corresponding to a key (in your example key `1`) to a variable for the scope of the update script `dict update ... { ... }`. `1 1` here reads as: Map the entry of key `1` to a local variable named `1`. You could also pick a different variable name `1 tmp1`, but `1` is just to maintain the spirit of your example.

Answer (score 1):

Based on  mrcalvin 's link- found this to work

```
% set d {key1 {key2 value1}}
% dictlappendsub d key1 key2 value2
key1 {key2 {value1 value2}}
% dictlappendsub d key1 key3 value3
key1 {key2 {value1 value2} key3 value3}
```

This might be achieved by:

```
# dictlappendsub dict key1 ... keyn value
proc dictlappendsub {dictName args} {
    upvar 1 $dictName d
    set keys [lrange $args 0 end-1]
    if {[dict exists $d {*}$keys]} {    ; **## What does this do!? WOW**
        dict set d {*}$keys [linsert [dict get $d {*}$keys] end [lindex $args end]]
    } else {
        dict set d {*}$keys [lrange $args end end]
    }
}
```

Comment: *What does this do!? WOW* `See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard command for doing this because the number of possible commands for all the different things that might be done gets too large; only common cases are provided for you (with the exact choice depending in part on what is technically unambiguous given that Tcl's dictionaries allow arbitrary values as keys *by design*). Instead, `dict update` and `dict with` are provided as tools to allow people to make their own solutions.

In particular, by making the *assumption* that we are appending *exactly one* list item and with `dict update`, `upvar` and some recursion, we can make this:

```
proc dict_lappend_item {dictVar args} {
    upvar 1 $dictVar d
    if {[llength $args] == 1} {
        lappend d [lindex $args 0]
    } else {
        set args [lassign $args key]
        dict update d $key inner {
            dict_lappend_item inner {*}$args
        }
    }
    return $d
}
```

Here's using it:

```
% set test [dict create]
% dict set test 1 "flps" "o1"
1 {flps o1}
% dict_lappend_item test 1 flps o2
1 {flps {o1 o2}}
% dict_lappend_item test 1 flps o3
1 {flps {o1 o2 o3}}
```

That looks like it is doing the thing you need. (Note that `dict lappend` doesn't make that assumption; it instead handles the append-multiple-items case, which has some true performance nasties if not treated specially in C code.)

---

You can plug the above procedure into `dict`.

```
set map [namespace ensemble configure dict -map]
dict set map additem ::dict_lappend_item
namespace ensemble configure dict -map $map
```

and then you can do:

```
% dict additem test 1 flps o4
1 {flps {o1 o2 o3 o4}}
```

Careful if you do this. Overriding standard subcommand implementations is possible, but a recipe for code that doesn't work if you're not uber-cautious about following the existing API.

Comment: The name `additem` was chosen to be obviously different to every other word in the script.